# Put each XQuery result on a new line

Tags: xml, formatting, xquery

Is it possible to put each XQuery result on a new line? I thought I remembered there was an attribute to set at the beginning of the document, but can't remember. :/

I have this .xq file:

```
(: declare default element namespace "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; :)
for $x at $i in doc("zoo.xml")//animal
return <li>{$i}. {$x/name/text()}</li>
```

I get correct results, but all of them are on a single line, when I really want something like:

```
<li>1. Zeus</li>
<li>2. Fred</li>
...
```

Is this possible? Thanks in advance for your answers! :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

...you can add a newline string as second part of the return clause:

```
(: declare default element namespace "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; :)
for $x at $i in doc("zoo.xml")//animal
return (<li>{$i}. {$x/name/text()}</li>, '&#xa;')
```

The way how results are serialized also depends on the specific XQuery processor.

Answer (score 10):

XQuery 3.0 provides a new serialization option `item-separator`, which can be specified in the query prolog:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:item-separator "&#xa;";

for $x at $i in doc("zoo.xml")//animal
return <li>{$i}. {$x/name/text()}</li>
```

Answer (score 5):

The [XQuery 3.1 Serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#adaptive-output) specification provides the new "adaptive" serialization mode, which outputs each XQuery result on a new line.

Some XQuery processors use this mode as new default.

Answer (score 4):

The XQuery engine you are using might have an option to indent the output. E.g. in Zorba, indent option works like this:

```
zorba -i -q 'for $x in 1 to 10 return <a/>'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a/>
<a/>
<a/>
<a/>
<a/>
<a/>
<a/>
<a/>
<a/>
<a/>
```